# Weak binding to model properties from subview

Tags: swiftui, memory-leaks, binding, operator-overloading, weak-references

I've encountered memory leak in SwiftUI view's models when using bindings.

1. I've created ObservableObject model like

```
final class Model: ObservableObject { 
   @Published var selectedValue: String?
}
```

2. I've created ContentView using this Model

```
struct ContentView: View { 
  @StateObject private var model = Model() 

  var body: some View { 
     SelectButton(selection: $model.selectedValue) 
  } 
}
```

3. I've implemented SelectButton this way

```
 struct SelectButton: View { 
   @Binding var selection: String? 
    @State private var isPresented = false 
    let options: [String] = ["One", "Two"]

    var body: some View { 
       Button { isPresented = true } label: {
        Text(selection ?? "Select") 
       }
       .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) { 
           VStack { 
               Text("List with options") 
               ForEach(options) { option in Text(option) }
            }
             
        }
    }
}
```

And now every time I push ContentView on screen
and then try to select using SelectButton new selectedValue
presenting sheet with list. Close this sheet by even simple pull to dismiss
Then Model observable object leak. And returning from ContentView
this Model isn't deallocated.
If I just enter ContentView and doesn't present SelectButton sheet than there is no leak.

There also isn't leak when Sheet view doesn't use any property from SelectButton. But then this view will be useless.

I can prevent leaking by using weak binding, for instance

```
func weakBinding<Value: ExpressibleByNilLiteral, O: ObservableObject>(_ object: O, keyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<O, Value>) -> Binding<Value> {
    Binding(
        get: { [weak object] in object?[keyPath: keyPath] ?? nil },
        set: { [weak object] in object?[keyPath: keyPath] = $0 }
    )
}
```

and

```
SelectButton(selection: weakBinding(model keyPath: \.selectedValue))
```

Can you have any idea how to better solve this memory leak.
It occures using .sheet(), .fullScreenCover(), and I can circumvent (prevent) it using custom .model() modifier but it wraps UIKit modal presentation underneath. So it seems that there is something wrong in SwiftUI.

Maybe it is possible at least implement custom weak binding functionality in Swift that is analog to `$viewModel.selectedValue` with other prefix like `#`
For instance I would like to have `#viewModel.selectedValue`

**UPDATE**

It seems that it is bug introduced by Apple in SwiftUI since new Xcode and iOS 17?

Memory leak on ObservableObject seems to happen each time you use sheet presentation in view refrencing this ObservableObject.

Minimal reproducible excample (you only need to push this TestView(viewModel: TestViewModel()) from root view. Then each time you open sheet and move back it causes memory leak.

```
final class TestViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text = "Test View"
    
    init() {
        print("DEBUG: init TestViewModel")
    }
    
    deinit {
        print("DEBUG: deinit TestViewModel")
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel: TestViewModel
    
    @State private var isPresented = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(viewModel.text)
            
            Button {
                isPresented = true
            } label: {
                Text("Open sheet")
            }
        }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented, content: contentView)
    }
    
    private func contentView() -> some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Sheet content")
        }
    }
}
```

I am still testing it but it seems that memory leak happens every time you present sheet where sheet content is defined in some
`var sheetContent: some View { }`

or
`func sheetContent() -> some View { }`

as long as it seems that there is no memory leak if you directly specify sheet view inside closure like this

```
.sheet(isPresented; $isPresented) { 
    Text("This doesn't causes memory leak") 
}
```

Unfortunatelly it work as long as you view doesn't have any reference to parent view or view model.

**Update 2**

Creating separate SheetView and presenting it directly doesn't leak parent view's view model.

```
struct SheetView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Sheet content")
    }
}

final class TestViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text = "Test View"
    
    init() {
        print("DEBUG: init TestViewModel")
    }
    
    deinit {
        print("DEBUG: deinit TestViewModel")
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel: TestViewModel
    
    @State private var isPresented = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(viewModel.text)
            
            Button {
                isPresented = true
            } label: {
                Text("Open sheet")
            }
        }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented, content: {
                SheetView()
            })
    }
    
    private func contentView() -> some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Sheet content")
        }
    }
}
```

**Update 3**

Usage of environment object like suggested by `malhal` also causes memory leak

Here is my tested code:

```
struct SheetView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: TestViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Sheet content")
    }
}

final class TestViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text = "Test View"
    
    init() {
        print("DEBUG: init TestViewModel")
    }
    
    deinit {
        print("DEBUG: deinit TestViewModel")
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel: TestViewModel
    
    @State private var isPresented = false
    @State private var flag = false
    
    private let variable = "Test"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(viewModel.text)
            
            Button {
                isPresented = true
            } label: {
                Text("Open sheet")
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented, content: {
            SheetView()
                .environmentObject(viewModel)
        })
    }
    
    private func contentView() -> some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Sheet content")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did experience in a similar case on iOS 17 only (not iOS 16), where the model (ObservableObject) created and owned by a parent view (via `@StateObject`) leaks when a sheet has been presented (here, using its own model). If the sheet will not be presented in the parent view, its model does not leak. There is no connection whatsoever from the parent model to the sheet or its model. IMHO, that's a sever bug in iOS 17.

Comment: yes this sheet causes view model to leak each time I refrence variable or function from view for sheet content like `.sheet(isPresented: $isPresented, content: { variable })` or `.sheet(isPresented: $isPresented, content: sheetContent)`

Comment: Only way it works for me is defining SheetView() directly inside sheet content closure like  `.sheet(isPresented: $isPresented, content: {  SheetView()  })`. But it works as long as you don't pass any variable there or binding `SheetView(variable: variable, flag: $flag)`. This SheetView causes memory leak again

Comment: Michał, please report a bug to Apple, so that it get high attention. ;)

Comment: Yeah I've reported yesterday. We cannot use new xcode, entrie app has a lot of memory leaks :(

Comment: @CouchDeveloper there are already some ignored reports.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77235312/3013748

Answer (score -2):

You're close but you need to fix a few things:

The object is usually called a Store, e.g.

```
final class ModelStore: ObservableObject { 
   @Published var models: Model[] = []

    static shared = ModelStore()
    static preview = ModelStore(preview: true) // fill with sample data for previews
}
```

Which has an array of your model types, structs since we are using Swift:

```
struct Model: Identifiable { 
   let id = UUID() // needed for ForEach
   var text: String = ""
   
   mutating func someLogic() { // in case you aren't familiar
}
```

Now use the environment so your store is available to all Views:

```
TopMostView()
    .environmentObject(ModelStore.shared)
```

Now when you bind to `$model.selectedValue` you won't have a leak.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var modelStore: ModelStore

    ...
    ForEach($modelStore.models) { $model in
        DetailView(text: $model.text)
```

```
struct DetailView: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    ...
```

If you want to create a temp model to edit then just use `@State var editingModel = Model()` or use a custom `Editor` state struct with a `Model` as a var.

For what you want to do with the button I think your Model struct will need a string for the option name, e.g. "One" and a `var bool isSelected`. If your option name is unique it can even be the Identifiable ID, e.g. `var id: String { optionName }`

Comment: When using `@State` for a model store not conforming to Observable, or alternatively, using `@State` for a model store where the macro `@Observable` has been applied, or alternatively using just a regular class instance (either macro Observable or not) it will leak when running on iOS 17 after presenting a sheet from the view where you have the model store. It's a bug in iOS 17. It will always leak using a regular class instance (which will be deallocated in iOS 16).

Comment: Best stick to structs for SwiftUI, clearly `Observable` has some major design flaws.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Yes I am sure it is bug introduced in iOS 17. We have typical. achitecture in swiftui (don't use EnvironmentObjects usually) 
But View + ViewModel (apple names it model or modelstore) and using `@State`  @Published @StateObject @ObservedObject`. 

Since iOS 17 sheet causes memoy leak on view model (ObservableObject) referenced form parent view that is presenting sheet. Usually you don't see huge sideeffects but in one part of up this memory leak breaked completle business logic in out app. 

malhal Your answer is wrong and doesn't address problem of memoy leaks in apple.

Comment: @malhal In **Update 3** I've added code that uses your approach with environment objects and it also causes memory leak.

Comment: @MichałZiobro update 3 is not quite right, it has to be like `.environmentObject(ModelStore.shared)`